# WebGL texture failure

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

While chrome updated to his newest version my WebGL application is no longer working...
The models are just black, because the texture won't load.

Here is the failure message. The textures are all power of 2, so I don't know where the problem is. It worked fine with Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m

> ```
> GL_INVALID_ENUM : glActiveTexture: texture was GL_LINE_LOOP 
>
>
>  WebGL: drawArrays: texture bound to texture unit 2 is not renderable.
> ```
>
> It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture
>    filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or
>    Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or
>    OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.

My draw call

```
   // draw the Triangles

   gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, Model.TriangleCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem.

The solution was to query another extension: oes_texture_float_linear; 
http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float_linear.txt
It adds filters to floating textures and now the code works again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us part of code?

Do you have something like this: (?)

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ...);
```

Read that:

```
GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if texture is not one of GL_TEXTUREi, where i ranges from 0 to (GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS - 1).
```

Few words about "is not renderable" here

https://twitter.com/mrdoob/status/346950885039030273

Do you use compressed textures?